# PHP to pass checkbox value to js then to other php

Tags: php, database, input, checkbox, insert

I have 3 files; index.php, script.js and displayprocess.php.

In index.php a select option is display for users to select what records they want to view. Essentially, in the index.php file you have 2 buttons: View and Submit.

In script.js; when the user click the view button the value of the select option will be pass through this js file.
I will just show you some parts of the code.

```
$("#viewrecord").click(function() {
            var e = document.getElementById("location");
            var nameoflocation = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            // sending ajax request
            $.ajax({

                url: 'displayprocess.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                         viewstore : viewstore, 
                         'viewstore_check':1,
                    },

            });
        });
```

This will then call displayprocess.php to display a dynamic table with checkbox. 
Below is part of the table code with the checkbox.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='selected[" .$row["location"]. "]' checked=''>" . "</td>";
```

Displaying the table is not the problem but identifiying which record the user checked on the checkbox. In another words how do i pass those data to the script.js then eventually send those data to displayprocess.php to save to database.

this is my code for getting the checked value

```
$("#deployrecord").click(function() {
            var checkBox = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked');

            // sending ajax request
            $.ajax({

                url: 'displayprocess.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                         viewstore : viewstore, 
                         'viewstore_check':1,
                    },

            });
        });
```

But i will get this errorr message:

Undefined index: checkBox

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your code reaches the point where your query is executed?

Comment: I think you should add your code block in otherwise there is not enough context to understand what the question is.

Comment: Sorry about that, please see the edited version above. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

I cannot really see the rest of your code so I'm not sure how you are setting the value in your checkboxes. But here is a reference of PHP's Validation Filters https://www.php.net/filter.filters.validate

Comment: hi, can you check the above question again i edited them. thank you